# const Struct parameter in C

Tags: c, struct, parameters, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm studying simple binary tree.
I saw a model answer and had a question.
In this code `Item` and `Tree` are structs.

```
typedef struct {
    char characters[20];
    char name[20];
} Item;

typedef struct node {
    Item item;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
} Node;

typedef struct tree {
    Node* root;
    int size;
} Tree;
```

And I'll show two function prototypes.

```
bool InTree(const Item* pi, const Tree* ptree);
Item* TreeSearch(Tree* ptree, const Item key);
```

One is using Item* and the other is using Item by parameter. I know what each means. But when `const` is used, I think there is no difference between these two. If we assumed the memory is big enough.

`const Item* pi` and `const Item key` which is better when used as a parameter for a function?
Is it about coding style problem or is it intended?

Comment: Please post the `structs` - otherwise we are going to have to second guess

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question, I don't get to seem the problem. Are you asking why is `const` used?

Comment: So, to clarify, you assume `Item key` would be passed as address, and actual value is not in stack, because Item is so big? And then `const Item key` could be passed as address to the "original" variable because const, avoiding any copying, and thus under the hood would be no different from passing pointer to const? Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const Item *pi` means that `*pi` or `*(pi + index)` (or `pi[index]`) cannot be modified.

`const Item key` means that `key` cannot be modified (after initialization in the case of a variable, or after assignment as part of the function call in the case of a function parameter).

---

```
bool InTree(const Item* pi, const Tree* ptree);
```

I guess that `InTree` searches whether the specific `Item` node pointed to by `pi` is present in the tree whose root node is pointed to by `ptree`. (I.e. it is searching for a pointer to the specific `Item` rather than searching for a matching `Item`.) There is no need to modify any `Item` in the tree or the `Item` pointed to by `pi`, so both parameters can be of type `const Item *` to indicate that nothing will be modified by the function.

---

```
Item* TreeSearch(Tree* ptree, const Item key);
```

I guess that `TreeSearch` searches the tree whose root node is pointed to by `ptree` to find a node that matches `Item key`. I guess that only the "value" parts of the `Item` will be compared with nodes in the tree and the "linkage" parts of the `Item` will be ignored.  I guess the function will return a pointer to the `Item` in the matching node in the tree if one is found, otherwise it will return a null pointer.

Declaring the parameter `key` as `const Item key` is a coding style issue.  It makes no difference to the caller of the function because arguments are passed by value.  It only makes a difference in the function definition, preventing the function body from modifying the value of the parameter.

I guess the parameter `ptree` could be declared as `const Tree *` assuming the function does not modify the `*ptree`.

I guess the function return type is `Item *` rather than `const Item *` because the caller of the function might want to modify the (indirectly) returned `Item` in some way.

---

As a side note, even if the `TreeSearch` function is defined as

```
Item* TreeSearch(Tree* ptree, const Item key)
{
    /* ... implementation omitted ... */
}
```

then it will match this declaration without the `const` qualifier

```
Item* TreeSearch(Tree* ptree, Item key);
```

so that `const` qualifier for parameter `key` really is superfluous in the *declaration* of the function, even if it is not superfluous in the *definition* of the function.

That does not apply to the declaration of the `InTree` function.

---

For `Item* TreeSearch(Tree* ptree, const Item key);`, if the type `Item` is considered "large", then it would be more practical to change the parameter `key` to `const Item *key` in order to reduce the function call overhead.  The programmer should use their best judgement about that.  The function would then be defined to find an `Item` node in the tree that *matches* `*key` (considering only the "value" parts of `Item` and ignoring the "linkage" parts), not to find the *specific* `Item` node pointed to by `key`.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* 1 */ void foo(Item *pi)
/* 2 */ void foo(const Item *pi)
/* 3 */ void foo(const Item * const pi)
```

All three will pass the reference to the struct, not the struct itself. The difference is :

1. the pointer `pi` and the referenced struct can be modified
2. the pointer `pi` can be modified, the referenced struct cannot be modified
3. the pointer `pi` and the referenced struct cannot be modified

```
/* 1 */ void foo(Item pi)
/* 2 */ void foo(const Item pi)
```

In both cases struct will be copied by value ie the whole struct will be passed to the function. If you modify the member it will not affect the original struct.

1. struct `pi` can be modified
2. struct `pi` cannot be modified

Comment: I think he's expecting that when you use `const Item pi` it will optimize out the copy and will just pass a pointer. This is allowed by the "as if" rule.

Comment: @Barmar I hope I made it clear that it will not optimize it this way

Answer (score 1):

Between these two approaches of declarations of parameters with the specifier `Item`

```
bool InTree(const Item* pi, const Tree* ptree);
Item* TreeSearch(Tree* ptree, const Item key);
```

the approach with declaration the parameter like `const Item* pi` is more preferable compared with the declaration `const Item key` because in the second case the whole object of the structure type that contains character arrays is copied instead of coping only a pointer to the object that is more efficient.